# How to add search function to browser

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I just checked http://www.dogpile.com/ and wanted to create a button like: `Add dogpile to your browser`. Can I know where to start from? Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an [OpenSearch](http://www.opensearch.org/Home) plugin, as described in [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/creating_opensearch_plugins_for_firefox) article.

This includes:

- A way to search your site (a pre-requisite)
- An XML file describing the search plugin
- An image for the provider
- In the page you want this to exist, a `<link rel="search" ... >` tag